# Compiler seems to not use includes

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-2015

I am defining a factory to create objects of the implementation of an interface. The factory includes the interface header as well as the implementation's header. Both classes are in the same namespace. The compiler however gives error C2065 among others when compiling the factory (IntelliSense resolves everything just right, if that counts for anything)

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "IDBConnector.hpp"
class IDBConnectorFactory
{
public:
  virtual ~IDBConnectorFactory() { }
  virtual std::shared_ptr<IDBConnector> createDBConnector() = 0; ///<  Create a new object of an implementation of the IDBConnector interface
};
```

The interface defines a lot of functions, which in my opinion don't do anything to that problem. All functions are pure virtual and are implemented in the implementation.

```
  #pragma once
  #include <string>
  #include "ConfigFormats.hpp"

  class IDBConnector
  {
  public:
    virtual ~IDBConnector(){};
    virtual bool connect() = 0;
    virtual std::string getSchema() = 0;
    ...
   };
```

The compiler output is:

```
  error C2065: "IDBConnector": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
  error C2923: "std::shared_ptr": "IDBConnector" ist kein gültiges template-Typargument für den _Ty-Parameter.
```

In english that should be the following:

```
  error C2065: "IDBConnector": undeclared identifier
  error C2923: "std::shared_ptr": "IDBConnector" invalid template argument for the _Ty-Parameter
```

Could it be that i messed up the configuration? I tried to disable the use of precompiled header, but it didn't change the compile errors.

I've created a dependency graph using doxygen to see where the circular dependency lies:
[image: God, this looks wild.]

I resolved the circularity by putting stuff from EDLBackend.hpp to a .cpp file and forward declaring IDBConnectorFactory and IDBConnector in EDLBackend.hpp.
Then i did the whole thing for another circular dependecy and tada, it works. Thanks guys!

[image: The resolved dependency. Still looks wild]

Comment: Please can you show the definition of `IDBConnector`

Comment: @MartinBonner sure, but its a wall of text.

Comment: You must have a circular include dependency.

Comment: Well, without it, it's really hard to say anything other than "it's an invalid parameter",  The question is, *why* is it invalid?

Comment: Hang on.  Sorry.  I just noticed the first line "nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner".

Comment: @juanchopanza Any tools for an easy check/graph? It's only my header files that could cause that behaviour, right?

Comment: You can get doxygen to build include dependency graphs with the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet `IDBConnector.hpp` starts out:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "IDBConnectorFactory.hpp"
```

Expanding that, but including the first few lines, we have:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
    // #pragma once
    // #include <memory>  - skipped
    // #incude "IDBConnector.hpp" - skipped because of #pragma once
    class IDBConnectorFactory
    { ....
```

So `IDBConnectorFactory` is defined without `IDBConnector` being defined.

The fix is that one of the headers has to stop including the other.  You can
probably remove the #include "IDBConnectorFactory.hpp" from IDBConnector.hpp and just replace with the single line:

```
    class IDConnectorFactory;
```

(That tells the compiler there is class, so it can create references and pointers, but no details.)

Comment: you're right, although it's not that simple. i've added the dependency graph for my file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you use multi-including protection in header files.
Try this:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = NO
```